# How to formatting list of text into 2 column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code below to process text data using tf idf in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import glob

files = glob.glob("Text/*.txt")

with open("all_data.txt","wb") as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f,"rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())


import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import nltk #import library nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize #import word_tokenize for tokenizing text into words 
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize #import sent_tokenize for tokenizing paragraph into sentences
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer #import Porter Stemmer Algorithm 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer #import WordNet lemmatizer 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords #import stopwords
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory #import Indonesian Stemmer
import re #import regular expression
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

file = open('all_data.txt', 'r')
t = file.read()
text_data = t

#casefolding
def casefolding(s):
    new_str = s.lower()  
    return new_str

cf = casefolding(text_data)

#remove punctuation from string
def removepunct(str):
    new_string =  re.sub(r"[\W]", " ", str)
    return new_string

rp = removepunct(cf)

#remove digit from string
def removeDigit(str):
    new_string =  re.sub(r"[0-9]", " ", str)
    return new_string

rd = removeDigit(rp)

#remove words in length 1-3
def removelg(str):
    new_string =  re.sub(r' \w{1,3} ', ' ', str)
    return new_string

rl = removelg(rd)

#remove multiple space
def removespace(str):
    new_string = re.sub(' +', ' ',str)
    return new_string

rms = removespace(rl)

#Stemming Indonesian
def stemmingIndo(str):
    factory = StemmerFactory()
    stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()
    return stemmer.stem(str)

stindo = stemmingIndo(rms)

#remove stopwords
def stpwrds(str):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('indonesian'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(stindo) 
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]  
    filtered_sentence = [] 

    for w in word_tokens: 
        if w not in stop_words: 
            filtered_sentence.append(w)
    return filtered_sentence

filt = stpwrds(stindo)

par = ' '.join(filt)

def word_tokenization(s):
    tokens = word_tokenize(s)
    return tokens
wordtoken = word_tokenization(par)
bowD = wordtoken

wordSet = set(bowD)

wordDict = dict.fromkeys(wordSet,0)

for word in bowD:
    wordDict[word]+=1

def computeTF(wordDict, bow):
    tfDict = {}
    bowCount = len(bow)
    for word, count in wordDict.items():
        tfDict[word] = count/float(bowCount)
    return tfDict

tf = computeTF(wordDict, bowD)

def computeIDF(docList):
    import math
    idfDict = {}
    N = len(docList)

    idfDict = dict.fromkeys(docList[0].keys(), 0)
    for doc in docList:
        for word, val in doc.items():
            if val > 0:
                idfDict[word] += 1

    for word, val in idfDict.items():
        idfDict[word] = math.log10((1+N) / float(val))

    return idfDict

idf = computeIDF([wordDict])

def computeTFIDF(tfBow, idfs):
    tfidf = {}
    for word, val in tfBow.items():
        tfidf[word] = val*idfs[word]
    return tfidf

tfidf = computeTFIDF(tf, idf)

df = pd.DataFrame({'weight': tfidf})

#test = df.sort_values('tfidf', ascending=False)
test = df.sort_values(by = 'weight', ascending=False)
print(test)
```

I have managed to run it and got the output below. I don't think there is error from this but I don't how to get the full output

```
             weight
butuh      0.026342
orang      0.019802
milik      0.009629
saudara    0.007267
hidup      0.006359
atur       0.006359
periksa    0.005450
hasil      0.005450
suka       0.004360
barang     0.003997
epps       0.003633
pengaruh   0.003270
perhati    0.003270
agresif    0.003088
salah      0.003088
laku       0.002907
prestasi   0.002907
gantung    0.002907
seksual    0.002907
muhammad   0.002725
rawat      0.002725
benda      0.002725
tolong     0.002725
manja      0.002543
percaya    0.002543
hadap      0.002543
harmonis   0.002543
gaul       0.002543
tekun      0.002362
ubah       0.002362
...             ...
widad      0.000908
hubung     0.000727
manusia    0.000727
ekspresi   0.000727
aktivitas  0.000727
taruh      0.000727
pilih      0.000545
masuk      0.000545
putus      0.000545
peka       0.000545
kait       0.000545
ambil      0.000545
sulit      0.000545
paham      0.000545
raih       0.000545
rutin      0.000545
didik      0.000545
laksana    0.000363
kuat       0.000363
mudah      0.000363
jaga       0.000363
patuh      0.000363
gigih      0.000363
tonjol     0.000182
konvensi   0.000182
lingkung   0.000182
sosial     0.000182
interaksi  0.000182
urus       0.000182
tarik      0.000182

[150 rows x 1 columns]
```

I get a truncated representation, but I want the full array. I want to see the 150 data in row.

Is there any way to do this? should i split into 2 column and how's it working?

Comment: Try converting it into a numpy array and print the array, to include more data, you could use `np.dtype`-float64 for the second column.

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas `.head()` method will print the dataframe with the number of rows you specify. You can try using this method and inserting the number of rows you would like to see. For example to see 150 rows, you can try

`print(test.head(150))`

Answer (score 0):

A for loop over each row of 'test' will work, print one row at a time. However it'll be slow to print so many times.
Let us know if that is sufficient.